# transforming a 7 digit integer number to unique alphanumeric value and vice versa

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to convert a 7 digit integer to 6 character alphanumeric value (ALL CAPS a). I don't want to translate the integer value, is there any other way I can do it ? encode it and decode with output value back to the function and get in input back again -

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 7200123 | ABC123 |
| ABC123 | 7200123 |
| 1234567 | 12X7S3 |
| 12X7S3 | 1234567 |

Ideally I should be able to pass any integer and get an encoded 6 character alphanumeric value and pass the 6 Character Alphanumeric value to get the integer back

Comment: what's the conversion rule? is it a static table, or do you have a specific function to apply?

Comment: No specific rule, integer numbers are provided from a transaction table, we can consider it as a one up number sequence that we want to encode before sharing with consumers

Comment: So, `7200 -> ABC`, `ABC -> 7200`, `34567 -> X7S3`, and `X7S3 -> 34567`? What is even happening here?

Comment: Convert the number from base-10 representation into base-36 representation. Done. Even needs only 4.5 characters.

Comment: @JörgWMittag base 10 to base 36 conversion should take care of it, thanks for the lead

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so this is how I was able to perform it, not showing 6 char values though but trade off is acceptable for now. Based on lead from @jorg

```
import base36

print(base36.dumps(7200345))
print(base36.loads("4abtl"))
```

[image: Output]

Comment: reply does not match the question. "4abtl" does not have 6 characters

Comment: yup thanks for pointing out. business is okay with the trade off, will continue to enhance the solution to extend this to 6 char value

Answer (score -1):

If you have 'no specific rule', so just a set of values, use a dictionary.

The 'default' dictionary holds your encryption (forward). Inverting that dict will give you the decoding, i.e., bring back the key, provided a value.

This requires your translation table to hold only unique tuples - i.e., no value may appear twice for different keys. But I think that's an (implicit) assumption underlying your original question anyway. If you had 2 different keys for the same output, that would be non-invertible and you would not be able to return a unique value.

```
from typing import Dict

translation_dict: Dict[int, str] = {7200123: 'ABC123', 1234567: '12X7S3'}

def encode(number: int) -> str:
    return translation_dict.get(number, None)

def decode(alphanumeric: str) -> int:
    inverse_dict: Dict[str, int] = {v: k for k, v in translation_dict.items()}
    return inverse_dict.get(alphanumeric, None)
```

Comment: Somehow you are supposed to _"be able to pass **any** integer and get an encoded 6 character alphanumeric value"_.

Comment: Only requires a dictionary with 2.176.782.336 entries :-D (1 billion, depending on how you interpret the question.)

Comment: Ok, then the question is underspecified.. If the question relates to defining a universally applicable, invertible function, but at the same time asks that there be "no specific" rule, this is going to be a bit of a challenge... If you want a general function, that is to be invertible, there clearly has to be a translation/masking/encoding rule